# Migrate Virtuemart from Joomla 1.5 to Joomla 3.3

Tags: joomla-3.x, joomla-3.3.x, virtuemart, joomla-1.5

My site was in Joomla 1.5 and I migrated it to Joomla 3.3. In my older site ie in Joomla 1.5 site there is virtuemart installed I want to migrate virtuemart to my new Joomla 3.3.

Please help.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to preserve your sanity, don't even try to perform migration manually.

I have used Daycounts VM Migrator https://www.daycounts.com/shop/virtuemart-3/virtuemart-2-migrator.htm for migrating five (5) VM1 shops to VM2 in Joomla 2.5, and I have only words of praise for that extension's quality, stability and scalability.

It's latest version now supports migrating to VM3 and Joommla 3 itself, and I Highly Recommend It to everyone in need of VM shop migration.